# can you create a 3d raised box using CSS or do you need to use images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d

I am trying to create a little 3d raised "panel" or "box" on my site. I found a similar example [on this page](http://www.onechosen.org/default.asp) where they have this page with windows that are "raised" off the page with a title box.  In this case, they are using an image for the whole box and just the text in the middle is actual text on the page.

I wanted to see if this can be replicated using CSS or I should really move over to photoshop for this sort of thing and do it all as images. (if i have to)

does anyone have any suggestions on if this can be replicated using pure html and css, javascript.

As a second question, if it has to be done using photoshop and images is there are any good place to get photoshop "templates" where you wouldn't have to put this together from scratch.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something similar using CSS3 for the fancy parts:

http://jsfiddle.net/RrfJb/ *(view in a WebKit browser such as Chrome)*

It can be made to work in "all browsers".

- For Firefox it's as easy as adding the `-moz` prefix versions.
- For IE, use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) for the gradients and box shadow, and [this tool](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/) to generate `transform` CSS.

---

```
.box {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #888 0%,#fff 30%);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #666;
    padding: 12px
}
.box > h2 {
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
    left: -21px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    font: bold 18px sans-serif
}
.box > p {
    clear: both
}
<div class="box">
    <h2>Welcome to website!</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks . . when you say it can be made to work in "all browsers" does that mean this code above only works in some browser . . i unfortunately need to support everything as a requirement  (including IE6 :( )

Comment: I literally just updated my answer to include pointers on how to make it work in IE6.

Comment: What is your exact definition of "all browsers"/"everything"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot with CSS3 including rotation, gradients and different fonts. The downside is that none of it apart from font embedding works in IE without various complexities.

You can't really do irregular bitmaps graphics like the paper crumpling, so you'll need an image for that.

Right now, I'd say that unless all the data is coming from a CMS, then the best way is to use an image for this, and possibly embed a font for the name at the bottom.

The second best way would be to just use the paper image, and to use CSS3 for the rest. Take a look at http://css3please.com/ for a good place to see the various properties.

Answer (score 0):

When using CSS3 you always have to be aware that people using old browsers may not be able to see what you intend. Using it progressively is the best way. Check out [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/03/using-css3-older-browsers-and-common-considerations/) article. 
In this particular case CC3 can add a drop-shadow. So if your OK with people who're using older browsers not being able to see the box shadow, go with CSS3. Otherwise use an image.